# MIB- access to data of base table in table augmentation

Tags: snmp, mib, snmpd, ietf

I am doing some research about different aspects of SMIv2 and MIB writing.

I have a given MIB file which has a table T1 and want to define a new table T2 at other MIB file that holds all columns of T1 and has some additional columns too. I found [this](https://silo.tips/download/inter-table-indexing-in-snmp-mibs) file and also this [page](http://pld.cs.luc.edu/courses/netmgmt/fall09/notes/06.html) that explains ways of addressing this issue.

But I have two questions that solving them by testing is hard to me. First, I want to use `snmpset` to add a new row in T2 and set value for columns that are defined in T1, but using snmpset with MIB file that contains T2 not T1. I *expect* that columns of T1 are *added* to T2 with specific columns of T2. Second, I wonder about OID of T1,T2 and relation between them. Again I expect to have a sub-tree containing columns of T1 and T2.

regards.